# query date from date to today with french format

Tags: php, sql

For each line of my column "CMD_DATE" in phpmyAdmin i have a date which has this format : 25/01/2013.

I want to make a query where i can select the result FROM 01/01/2013 to today.

Can i do it with this format : day/month/year ? 
How can i do it from date to today in a query ?

I need the query in PHP, i use PDO and it has to be something like this :

```
foreach ($query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM commandes WHERE CMD_FRN_ID = '$frn_id' AND CMD_DATE ...") as $donnees):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem when stocking dates like this is you end up with a string instead of a date, so you can't really do something with it.

I'd advise you to start using US format from now on, there's a datetime type in SQL you might aswell use it...

Hopefully, there's a solution. With MySQL 4.1.1 or higher it's fairly easy, you can convert a string to a date with STR_TO_DATE().

```
SELECT * FROM commandes WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CMD_DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND CURDATE();
```

That should work.